# zsh: command not found: pod // Cocoapods Xcode // Pod install not found

Tags: xcode, macos, terminal, operating-system, cocoapods

Cocoapods is already installed in the latest version but simply when I uninstalled and installed again the commands related to pod are no longer recognized. I think it would probably be an export path that I didn't put in my .zshrc file because I don't know what to put. Below is what I put in my .zshrc file.

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
export RBENV_ROOT=/usr/local/var/rbenv
export GEM_HOME=$HOME/.gem
export PATH=$GEM_HOME/bin:$PATH
export GEM_HOME=$HOME/Software/ruby
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/Software/ruby/bin
```

Unfortunately I don't understand anything about the file and directory path